# Javascript For Loop with If statement and Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I want the array to start printing from the second element of the Array **[2...]**.. but there is something I couldn't understand. I wrote an if statement to achieve that, as shown below. However, it doesn't return the wanted result. I mean, It starts printing from the beginning of the Array!!

```
let start = 0;
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "A", "B", "C", 4];

for (let i = start; i < mix.length; i++) {
  if (mix[i] === start) {
    continue;
  }
  document.write(`${mix[i]} <br>`);
}
```

But, when I replace the "mix[i]" with only "i" as shown below, it returns the wanted result and starts printing from the second element.

```
let start = 0;
let mix = [1, 2, 3, "A", "B", "C", 4];

for (let i = start; i < mix.length; i++) {
  if (i === start) {
    continue;
  }
  document.write(`${mix[i]} <br>`);
}
```

Updated: Thus, the question is what the difference between the first if and the second if, and why the first if "mix[i]" doesn't print the wanted result while the second one it works!!

I appreciate your help.

Comment: the item is not the index.

Comment: `i` starts with value `0`, and there is no element which equals `0` in `mix` so your condition in the first snippet is never true.

Comment: Why not just using `for (let i = 1; i < mix.length; i++) ... ` if you want to start from the second element in your array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the array value in that position for the first example and the index on the second example.
For the first code your conditional is:

```
if (mix[i] === start)
```

In this case, mix[i] will be the value stored in that index, so for the first iteration it will be mix[0], that will be 1 in your array. 1≠0 so it won't go to the continue and therefore print it.

In your second code, the conditional is:

```
if (i === start)
```

In this case you are actually using the index position, not the array value for that index. That's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

mix[i] === start

here mix[0] === 1 that's why if block gets skipped, because start=0; and i is also 0 that's why it's the correct output in second example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).